# Angular Decimal pipe to display significant digits

Tags: angular

How to use the Angular Decimal pipe to display the most 5 significant digits from a number as follows:

```
123.456789 => 123.45
12.3456789 => 12.345
0.12345678 => 0.12345
0.00123456 => 0.00123
1234567.89 => 1234567
```

Some extreme cases

```
12         => 012.00
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be as follows,

```
  <h1>{{ amount |  number:'3.2-2'}} </h1>
```

**`'3.2-2'`** means:

- A minimum of 3 digit will be shown before decimal point
- It will show at least 2 digits after decimal point
- But not more than 2 digits

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/TtXzN3hFrnqxV9vwSihA?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I am looking for is to keep only the most significant 5 digits. That format will not work on the second example.

Comment: In that case write your own pipe

Comment: Excellent explanation